# Pointer to a file pointer, how do I do it?

Tags: c, pointers

To get it out of the way immediately, this is an homework assignment, I really want to solve it myself so just answer the question and do not spread all the StackExchange love and point out more potential problems in my code and I will appreciate it very much! :)

What I have problem with is that I am trying to make a pointer to a file pointer. In my main function I created FILE * fp; witch I pass to a function called open_file(). What I then want to do is to pass the fp pointer to another function I have written that parse through each word. This is the function I am calling.

```
int
open_file(FILE * fp)
  {
    /*Open the text file*/
    fp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
      {
        return 2;
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

The way I pass the file pointer to this function from main() is like this

```
ret = open_file(&fp);
```

The compiler catch no errors and compile successfully, but instead of scanning the file and print out each word the terminal just freezing. If I instead do everything in open_file(), that is create the file pointer, calling the parser function and so on it works, also if I open the file directly in main.

The flags I use is -g -Wall -Werror and -Wextra

Comment: Dont hard-code the name of the file in your function. Instead, pass it as argument

Comment: So you don't want to enhance your coding skills and don't want to profit from the knowledge of experienced users? You should work on your attitude.

Comment: this function is a little useless

Comment: Any reason you don't `return fp`? Follow the library and `return NULL` on error. Why pass a parameter at all? And even if: pass the file-name via `const char *`

Comment: @Stargateur I agree that it is useless. I just got frustrated that I could not get it to work. And because of it I learned something about pointers. Thats how it is when you are starting to learn something new.

Comment: @Salviati Read this, I think that it was your problem https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: @Olaf No reason really. Did not think about that. It would be a bit more simple I agree on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consequently implement your idea, introduce another level of indirection:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

...

int
open_file(FILE ** pfp)
  {
    assert(pfp != NULL);

    /*Open the text file*/
    *pfp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");
    if (*pfp == NULL)
      {
        return -1; /* By convention -1 indicates failure. */
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

Use it like this:

```
int
open_file(FILE ** pfp);

...


FILE * fp;
int ret = open_file(&fp);
```

---

Nicer would be:

```
int
open_file(const char * file_name, FILE ** pfp)
  {
    int result = 0;

    assert(file_name != NULL);
    assert(pfp != NULL);

    *pfp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (*pfp == NULL)
      {
        result = -1; /* By convention -1 indicates failure. */
      }

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Edit: Do you know why I can't just do FILE ** fp ?

Comment: @Salviati: `pfp`, `fp`, `wtf`.. its just names .. call it what you want, those names are gone after compilation anyways! ;-)

Comment: @Salviati: I used `pfp`  as `FILE**` is a "p"ointer to  a "f"ile "p"ointer.

Comment: Sorry that question came out wrong. What I ment was that ** is a pointer to a pointer, right? So why to I have to keep puting a * before I call the pointer? For example "*pfp = fopen(file_name, "r");"

Comment: @Salviati: You want to read on what this `*`-operator, which also is called "*dereferencing*"-operator actually does.

Comment: @Salviati: `pfp` is a local variable. If you'd write to it *directly*, the calling side would not reflect this.

Comment: Exactly, did not know it was called a dereferencing operator, will look it up. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe in main you declared fp as pointer, in your case it wouldn't work because you pass pointer to *fp which means when you open a file pointer to this file is on stack of function open_file, when you get out of function, you loose this pointer. You can do it in three (or more) different ways:

First is return FILE pointer:

```
FILE *open_file(void)
{
    return fopen("mate.txt", "r");
}
```

> FILE *fp = open_file();

Or the other option is to pass pointer to pointer *fp:

```
int open_file(FILE **fp)
{
    /*Open the text file*/
    *fp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");
    if(*fp == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> FILE *fp;
>
> open_file(&fp);

Or just plainly in main:

> FILE *fp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");

Comment: @alk Thanks, and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function the following way

```
int
open_file(FILE ** fp)
  {
    /*Open the text file*/
    *fp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");
    if( *fp == NULL)
      {
        return 2;
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

You can not define the function like

```
int
open_file(FILE * fp)
          ^^^^^^^^
  {
    /*Open the text file*/
    fp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");
    if( fp == NULL)
      {
        return 2;
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

and call it like

```
open_file( fp );
```

because in this case the function will deal with a copy of the original pointer. Function parameters are its local variable. Any changes of a copy of an argument does not influence on the argument itself. The original argument will be unchanged.

Comment: I fought about this too, a pointer to a pointer. But I get the error: "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘FILE {aka struct _IO_FILE}’ from type ‘FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}’
   *fp = fopen("mate.txt", "r");" (sorry posted wrong error code)

Comment: @Salviati If you defined in the caller the pointer like FILE *fp; and then called the function like ret = open_file(&fp);   then the code should compile.

Comment: @Salviati: Where is Vlad's code significantly different form mine?

Comment: I do not know, but I can not get it to work. It should work, I agree with you on that. Give me a minute to try it again

Comment: Sorry, forgot something and that why it did not compile correctly. Completely my bad